# How to make http get JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Hy I'm new in Jquery. I want send data to http but i don't know ho to send data when use class.
**This my html**

```
<div class="action-lock">
  <div class="toggle-pane">
    <div class='unique' id='switch'>
      <div class='toggle-text-off'>Unlocked</div>
      <div class='glow-comp'></div>
      <div class='toggle-button'></div>
      <div class='toggle-text-on'>Locked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this **my JQuery**

```
$('.unique').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');
});
```

How to send http get in `Locked` and `Unlocked`. Some example URL like this    `localhost/web.php?tN=locked` or `localhost/web.php?tN=unlocked`. Please help me to know how to send http get if condition like this. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand quite what you're asking. You're asking how to **POST** the contents of those two DIVs to an external page? For that you would use AJAX or XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Send data to where? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: what is the meaning of send HTTP get ??

Comment: You shouldn't be using a "get" request to update data. You should "post" (or "put").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get) like,

```
$('.unique').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');
   // pass unlocked if it has class toggle-on, otherwise pass locked
   var data = {tN:($(this).hasClass('toggle-on')?'unlocked':'locked')};
   $.get('http://localhost/web.php',data,function(response){
      console.log(response);
   });
});
```

Comment: Your previous code work corectly. I want make 2 condition locked and unlocked and class in 'toggleClass' not always 'toggle-on'. I make some condition last position from toggleClass. But your code work corectly thank